# Outlook 2013/2016 ignores word-break: break-all in anchor and span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an html e-mail with a table where a cell contains a variable {descriptionLinkified}. The variable contains text input by a user. As this text can include urls I use javascript to search for urls in the text and put `<a>` tags around them. Additionally I apply an inline css style to split the link:

```
function linkify(text) {
var urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '" style="word-break: break-all;"><span style="word-break: break-all;">' + url + '</span></a>';
});
} 
var descriptionLinkified = linkify(description);
```

I want to keep the url as display name for the anchor as well because directly seeing the complete url might be important when receiving the e-mail. So replacing the display name with a shorter text is not an option.

The rest of the description in the cell should break normally. The final html after applying the javascript then looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto auto 0px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none; border-top-color: rgb(199, 199, 199); border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;" valign="top" width="340">
            <strong>Description:</strong></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none; border-top-color: rgb(199, 199, 199); border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; -ms-word-break: break-all; -ms-word-wrap: break-word;" valign="top" width="340"><a href="https://books.google.de/books?id=QdNxpPD3QqAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=sharepoint+site+collection&source=bl&ots=oqaA_WQ3UX&sig=ec7Bw6RikAd2f8D9DqmVx0bnP8w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFksmNtZnSAhVsOpoKHbMyA884ChDoAQhhMAk" style="word-break: break-all;"><span style="word-break: break-all;">https://books.google.de/books?id=QdNxpPD3QqAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=sharepoint+site+collection&source=bl&ots=oqaA_WQ3UX&sig=ec7Bw6RikAd2f8D9DqmVx0bnP8w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFksmNtZnSAhVsOpoKHbMyA884ChDoAQhhMAk</span></a></br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Depending on the urls Outlook only splits the url into the second line which makes the table overflow.
e.g.:

```
    https://books.google.de/books?id=QdNxpPD3QqAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=sharepoint+site+collection&source=bl&ots=oqaA_WQ3UX&sig=ec7Bw6RikAd2f8D9DqmVx0bnP8w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFksmNtZnSAhVsOpoKHbMyA884ChDoAQhhMAk
```

Outlook splits the url into

first line:

```
    https://books.google.de/books?
```

second line:

```
    id=QdNxpPD3QqAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=sharepoint+site+collection&source=bl&ots=oqaA_WQ3UX&sig=ec7Bw6RikAd2f8D9DqmVx0bnP8w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFksmNtZnSAhVsOpoKHbMyA884ChDoAQhhMAk
```

If I include `word-break: break-all` in the `td` inline style it works 100% in Outlook, but then, of course, also the non-url parts of the text are split.

Does anyone know why Outlook accepts the attribute when it's in the `td` tag, but handles it differently when it's in an anchor?

Any recommendations on how to solve this problem?